# flutter :how can I fetch data from json?

Tags: json, flutter

I trying fetch data from json by below code,but in this process I getting a error (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'). Please help  me in this

json structure is below 
 `[{id: 1, fname: Semester Fees, sname: 1st Semester, fee_amount: 4000, status: 0}, {id: 2, fname: Admission Fees, sname: 2nd Semester, fee_amount: 4000, status: 0}]`

```
 String url = 'http://192.168.42.124/my_payment/getcoursefee.php';
  List data;
  Future<String> makeRequest() async {
    var response = await http
        .post(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
    body: {
      "student_id": "261",

    });

    setState(() {
      var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
     Student student =new Student.fromJson(extractdata);
     print(student.studentId);
     print(extractdata);
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.makeRequest();
  }
```

my student class is below

```
class Student{
  String studentId;


  Student({
    this.studentId,
  });

  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return Student(
      studentId: parsedJson['id'],

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The JSON in your example is a List, not a Map. So, what is unclear to you?

Comment: how can i get the list value

Comment: The issue is that you are getting JSON list and you are trying to pass it to constructor where is expected a Map. And also that you are passing multiple entities. You have to split the list in for cycle and create multiple objects from those entities inside. See the @AndreyTurkovsky solution, that is what you want!

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
for (map in extractdata) {
  Student student = new Student.fromJson(map);
  print(student.studentId);
  print(map);
}
```

Somethimg like this